# ember-cli served via virtual box violates content security policy

Tags: ember.js, virtualbox

I have a fresh `ember-cli v.0.1.2` application. I serve ember within virtual box, and access the webpage from the host machine via Host-Only configured network adapter, at `192.168.56.102`.

When I run `ember serve` from the virtual box and visit `192.168.56.102` from the host, I get these errors on the console:

```
 [Report Only] Refused to load the script 'http://192.168.56.102:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' localhost:35729 0.0.0.0:35729".
ember-cli-live-reload.js:5 (anonymous function)

livereload.js?snipver=1:193 [Report Only] Refused to connect to 'ws://192.168.56.102:35729/livereload' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:35729 ws://0.0.0.0:35729".
```

I tried various configurations using [ember-cli-content-security-policy](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy) without luck:

```
 contentSecurityPolicy: {
    'default-src': "'none'",
    'script-src': "'self'",
    'font-src': "'self'",
    'connect-src': "'self'",
    'img-src': "'self'",
    'style-src': "'self'",
    'media-src': "'self'"
  }
```

How do I solve these errors for virtual box development?

**Edit**:

So according to this solution: [EmberCspTutorial](https://www.justinbull.ca/private/csp/), and the blog post: https://blog.justinbull.ca/how-to-configure-csp-in-your-ember-cli-app/

This configuration fixes the errors:

```
  ENV.contentSecurityPolicy = {
      'default-src': "'none'",
      'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-eval' 192.168.56.102:35729",
      'font-src': "'self'",
      'connect-src': "'self' ws://192.168.56.102:35729",
      'img-src': "'self'",
      'style-src': "'self'",
      'media-src': "'self'"
  };
```

There is also 30 min video explaining all of this, but is it ok I have to use some hardcoded ip that is likely to change like this, a comprehensive explanation will be accepted as an answer.

#### How to Enable CSP for `data:application/font*`

I have included some fonts and now I get these errors, what is the CSP configuration to supress these:

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the font 'data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRk9UVE8AAAVwAAoAAAAABSg…IAeQAgAEkAYwBvAE0AbwBvAG4ALgAAAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self' data:application/* http://fonts.gstatic.com".

192.168.56.102/:1 [Report Only] Refused to load the font 'data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAALAIAAAwAwT1MvMggjCB…BiAHkAIABJAGMAbwBNAG8AbwBuAC4AAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self' data:application/* http://fonts.gstatic.com".
```

According to [reference](http://content-security-policy.com/#source_list) this works:

```
  ENV.contentSecurityPolicy = {
      'default-src': "'none'",
      'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-eval' 192.168.56.102:35729",
      'font-src': "'self' data: http://fonts.gstatic.com",
      'connect-src': "'self' ws://192.168.56.102:35729",
      'img-src': "'self'",
      'style-src': "'self' fonts.googleapis.com",
      'media-src': "'self'"
  };
```

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the solution, and add it as a self-answer.

Comment: Where do you put the ENV.contentSecurityPolicy block ?

Comment: @JoePrivett - In your `enviroment.js` file

Comment: You should not have `unsafe-eval` in your `script-src` - it defeats the purpose of using a CSP in the first place. If you do need it, only add it for the development environment.