# Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using `urlive` library to load thumbnail images using the link.

Outside of a Chrome extension the functionality works perfect. But while running the same functionality in a Chrome extension I was getting the error:

> "Refused to load the script `'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=jQuery1111091462301090359…22+and+xpath%3D%22*%22+and+compat%3D%22html5%22&format=xml&_=1417426473922'` because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: `"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#thumbnail_url').on('input propertychange', function () {
    console.log('called');
    $('#thumbnail_url').urlive({
      callbacks: {
        onStart: function () {
          console.log('called1');
          $('.loading').show();
          $('.urlive-container').urlive('remove');
        },
        onSuccess: function (data) {
          $('.loading').hide();
          $('.urlive-container').urlive('remove');
        },
        noData: function () {
          $('.loading').hide();
          $('.urlive-container').urlive('remove');
        }
      }
    });
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

I have tried all the possibilities. But I did not get the answer. Still the error raising for me while calling the `yahooapis`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with the chromeapp then forget about `urlive` library. The 'urlive` will take the yahooapis and the yahooapis doesn't work on building the chrome app. It keeps raising the error. So better go with other library.

Answer (score 1):

Add the yahoo domain to the rule: `"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://query.yahooapis.com"`

For more information: http://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this previous. It doesn't worked for me :(

Comment: paste the error when you use this rule plz. also see my recent question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206351/ember-cli-served-via-virtual-box-violates-content-security-policy

Comment: In the manifest.json file I have given conten_script_policy: ""script-src 'self' https://query.yahooapis.com; object-src 'self'". Even thought I was facing the same error.

Comment: @user3484319 It's not `content_script_policy`, it's `content_security_policy`. Make sure you're setting it correctly.

Comment: sorry. My mistake while typing. It was conten_security_policy itself.

Comment: Ah, right. **This won't work, because Chrome won't allow HTTP origins.** Load the script over HTTPS and add the origin to CSP.