# Chrome app: Ajax query is't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, google-chrome-app

I wrote a simple chrome app which send ajax query over http and parse respond. I used only JQuery. At next, I try rewrite it using Backbone and Require and I met a lot of problems, but one of them confuses me. 
I have collection:

```
define([
  'backbone',
  'js/models/someModel',
], function(Backbone, SomeModel){
    var SomeList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: SomeModel,
      url: function(){
        return 'http://somedomain.com/some/parameters';
      },
      parse: function(response){
        data = parseData(response);
        return data;
      },
    });
    return SomeList;
  });
```

As a result I receive error in console line:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://somedomain.com/some/parameters' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

But previous app, used only JQuery, works well:

```
function getData(qStr, parseData){
    var data;
    $.ajax(qStr)
    .done(function (d) {
      data = parseData(d);
    })
    .fail(function (e, g, f) {
      alert('Some error happens!');
    });
    return data;
  }
```

What does it depend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27225463/2333214

Comment: Do you want say Backbonejs doesn't work with Chrome app?

Comment: You didn't include your working jQuery attempt. unless you share the working jQuery code and the similar Backbone code plus the differences in environment at which you ran these, we can't help you much. You think the problem lies with `Backbone` and looks at it with that mindset. The problem could be entirely at something else that you did while migrating to backbone. Please read [ask]